# Unable to send form data into MongoDB database using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, mongodb, bootstrap-4

So I've been trying to get the data from my form and input it into my database for ages and it just isn't working. There are no errors and nothing is logging.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Signup for NGOs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="mt-4 mr-4 ml-4" id="form" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter name of NGO">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Contact Information</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Contact Number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="requirements">Requirements (Seperate by Commas)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="requirements" placeholder="Requirements">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="signup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

// I've replaced my original username and password with placeholders
var uri = "mongodb+srv://username:password@helpbook-rlpsi.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";

var dbConn = MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    dbConn.then(function(db) {
        delete req.body._id; // for safety reasons
        dbConn.db("NGOs").collections("partners").insertOne(req.body);
        console.log('test');
    });
});
```

I don't know what's going wrong. My data isn't being uploaded to the database and for some reason none of the console.log() statements are being executed.

Comment: can you console log before `dbConn.then` and check if `req.body` exists? if not maybe use `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in your form

Comment: Nope. I tried both and there was still no change. Nothing is getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

The promise probably resolves before the signup handler is called.

Try the following:

```
var dbConn = MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
dbConn.then(function(client) {
    app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
        delete req.body._id; // for safety reasons
        client.db("NGOs").collections("partners").insertOne(req.body);
        console.log('test');
    });
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: I tried this and my terminal still doesn't print anything. It's just stuck at node signup.js. After that nothing happens. I changed req.body to {name: "john"} just to see if that makes a difference but it doesn't.

Comment: New hypothesis, changed my answer.

Comment: Tried this. Nothing got printed. I even tried to print out req.body but nothing got printed.

Comment: You're sure the form is actually submitting? I see no action property defined on your form. Try adding action="/signup" to your form in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question specifically, you are not using any `action` in your form.

```
<form class="mt-4 mr-4 ml-4" id="form" method="post" action="/signup">
...
</form>
```

So it is not getting posted to your route. (That's why I specifically asked if console logging before the dbconn is working or not)